# Is it faster to traverse the DOM from a cached selector than to find an ID'd element in the DOM?

Tags: jquery, optimization, dom-traversal

There are a lot of questions about whether or not finding an element is faster via class or id or some other selector. I'm not interested in that. I want to know if you have:

```
var link = $(this); //let's say you're in a click handler
```

Is it faster to find the container by doing

```
var container = link.closest('.container'); //assume container is .container
```

or

```
var container = $('#mycontainer'); //assume same element as above
```

I'm asking this question not just for the particular scenario above (ok, well, yes, for this scenario too) but for cached traversal vs. creating a fresh jQuery object that has an ID. I notice in a lot of my code I tend to do the former method (since it can lend itself to being more dynamic), but I was always curious if it was faster to do it the latter way.

Thanks

Comment: my suspicion is that the latter is faster, but did you test it? It would be pretty easy to knock up a test harness...

Comment: I'm not sure if this information is outdated and corrected with the most recent iterations of jQuery, but I'm pretty sure that `.closest()` is relatively slower than other alternatives.

Comment: i actually created a jsperf: http://jsperf.com/cached-dom-traversal-vs-new-id-selection looks like ID is definitely the fastest, finding by class is next.

Answer (score 2):

I would think that, cached selector or not, it would be faster to use the id selector. The ID selector is pretty much a direct dictionary lookup vs the cached/closest combination which is like a dictionary lookup, followed by a tree traversal.

http://jsperf.com/traverse-from-cached-selector-vs-id-selector

The fastest lookup would be done with the native documentGetElementById function.

```
var container = $(document.getElementById('MyContainer'));
```

Comment: it looks like traversing the tree is generally slower, which makes me wonder how good it is to use a cached object to then traverse from...

Comment: When it comes to traversing, I generally use cached objects to find collections of children elements. i.e. `$cachedObject.find('.untoggled-children').toggle().toggleClass('untoggled-children toggled-children');`

But when it comes to finding a single element, that has an id, I will always use `$(document.getElementById('myid'))`.