# jQuery: reduce DOM traversal by selecting elements out of variable?

Tags: jquery, performance, dom

I have a long list of DOM elements that I'm grabbing attributes out of to save to an object.

It seems like an overuse of DOM manipulation to use the jQuery selector over and over.

```
var a = $('input[name=a]:checked').val(),
    b = $('input[name=b]')is(':checked'),
    c = $('input[name=c]').val();
```

I'm thinking there might be a way to do something like `var $form = $('#form');` and then using `$form.find('input[name=a]:checked')` or `$form.children('input[name=b]')` or `$form.filter('input[name=c]')`. But these examples are off. I believe that because I didn't select the elements themselves, that selecting their parent element will not prevent jQuery from having to repeatedly peruse the DOM. Is that true?

Another option may be to add another class to all of the elements specifically for this (:/), but for some reason that seems weird. It *would* give me an array, though, which I assume I could use to prevent repeated DOM traversing? Something like this:

```
var $formElementArray = $('.the_elements_you_wanted');
```

and then using filter?

```
var a = $formElementArray.filter('input[name=a]:checked').val(),
    b = $formElementArray.filter('input[name=b]')is(':checked'),
    c = $formElementArray.filter('input[name=c]').val();`
```

Is this the best way to do it? Is there a best practice for this kind of thing?
It does seem a bit lame that I have to go add a class specifically to prevent too much DOM traversal since some of the elements I'm manipulating wouldn't have been grouped together otherwise, but if that's the case, c'est la vie.

Comment: If there are many elements, the best way is using `.filter()` method. And if you are worried about performance then use Vanilla JavaScript instead of jQuery.

Comment: Also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424975/is-it-faster-to-traverse-the-dom-from-a-cached-selector-than-to-find-an-idd-ele

Comment: ALL performance questions should be resolved by testing your alternatives in a performance measuring framework like jsFiddle.  Your best best would be to put ids on these elements so you can select them directly with `document.getElementById('myInputA')` or with `$('#myInputA')` if you still want to use jQuery.

Comment: Do you have all the elements on the page at once, or will you be adding more elements dynamically after page load? What does your complete HTML look like? What things do you want to fetch from the DOM nodes? Just `:checked` and `val()`?

Comment: @Dogbert In this instance, I'm not adding elements dynamically, and yes—just checked and val so far. Don't think I'll have to check for anything other than those.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ah, cool. I didn't realize jsfiddle helped do performance testing. It's really better to select 20 elements by ID individually out of the DOM rather than grab all of a single class in one sweep, though? That seems counter-intuitive. Does ID have some magical pointer mechanics going on, or is it just that it stops looking once it finds the first (and only) instance?

Comment: Answering my own comment above, according to Sourabh's link—yes, IDs basically have magical pointer abilities. Haven't tested to see if 20 ID lookups is faster or slower than the filter method yet. Could be a case by case basis depending on how much structure there is to traverse... Passing out right now, though. Will test tomorrow. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Check out [JSPERF.COM](http://jsperf.com/find-remove-vs-empty) as well. How many thousands of inputs are you going to traverse? I'd not worry about performance until there were at least (at least!) 100 of them.

Comment: @aminimalanimal, could you create an actual test case of what processing you want to do (on jsfiddle or something)? You can't really optimize something without having real code which does all the actions you want to optimize.

Comment: @Dogbert I'm hesitant to make this question specific to my code, as the intention was to figure out a best practice to start defaulting to. I do recognize now, thanks to everyone who commented, that there can _possibly_ be additional improvements made on a case by case basis, but jfriend00's test seems pretty definitive. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in my comments, you MUST test any performance questions like this if you really want to know the answer and you probably must test in several different browsers.

Here's a simple test case of five different scenarios: http://jsperf.com/scoped-selector-perf-test

1. Global search by name (your original code)
2. Scope the search to just the parent form
3. Give each item a unique id and just search for the id directly
4. Use a common class and filter each item by name from the common class
5. Use plain javascript by id

Running these in Chrome v26, of the jQuery options (1-4), search for each item by a unique id is the fastest.  13x faster than the global search by name, 7x faster than filtering a common class, 4x faster than scoping to a form parent.

The plain javascript search by id is 17x faster than the fastest jQuery option and 223x faster than your original code.  Similar results were seen in Firefox and IE10.

### Some Conclusions:

1. Scoping the search to a common parent does help, but not as much as using faster selectors to start with
2. Searching by `tag[name="xxx"]` is quite slow
3. Searching by id is fast
4. `document.getElementById("a")` is significantly faster than `$('#a')`

Comment: Wow. I knew jQuery was slower, but I had no idea it was _that much slower_! Thank you.